# Is it possible to add a class from external stylesheet into the css of another class?

Tags: html, css

This has been bugging me for so long.

Is this possible?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/una/CSSgram/master/source/css/cssgram.min.css">

<style>
.posts img{
color:black;
background:red;}
</style>
```

How do i apply a class from the external stylesheet into the `.posts{}` css ?

Comment: You can't. Instead apply the `posts` class **and** the class from the external stylesheet to the HTML element.

Comment: I want the css to work with the images in a html element only.

Answer (score 0):

If external class is using the same classes or IDs and if it's loaded after **your** CSS classes, it will overwrite them.

In this particular case, the following code:

```
<style>
.posts{
color:black;
background:red;}
</style>
```

will be overwritten by imported style sheet in case it comes **before** the external stylesheet has been loaded.

You can find out more about **CSS Hierarchy** [here.](http://www.nzwhost.com/article/understanding-css-hierarchy)